# replace trailing zeros regex with dot(.) and comma(,) including delimiter ,

Tags: php, regex

I use this regular expression to remove trailing zeros from numbers with dot(`.`) delimiter:

```
(?:(\.\d*[1-9])|\.)0*$
```

and I'm replacing with `$1`.

example:

- 9.50
- 2.00
- 3.06
- 3.000

it will give me:

- 9.5
- 2
- 3.06
- 3

But it doesn't seem to work the same way with comma(`,`). I tried this but with no luck:

```
(?:(\,\d*[1-9])|\,)0*$
```

I'm new to PHP and this is my first question here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't the '.' be escaped in ur original regexp?

Comment: @RedBaron: the dots were escaped, but some of the backslashes weren't showing because the OP didn't use code formatting.

Answer (score 3):

If these are separate strings, numbers only, then use: `[.,]?0*$` and replace it with an empty string.

Comment: Both of them worked!!These numbers are prices wich im receiving them with both delimiters ,so i have to remove them.The only problem was the percent(%) symbol which i had to remove it first. Thank you guys!!

Comment: The percent symbol was for discounts with the same format as prices.

Comment: Six characters!  I came up with two solutions, one using a conditional and the other with a branch-reset group, and you solve it with a six-character regex.  I am humbled. :D

Comment: Sorry but we have to assume that the same string gives me numbers with both delimters like this $prices=30.00  or $prices=25,50 .The above solutions work prefectly if there is a comma but with dot a get this 60.00=6. Any suggestions? Caution:I do not have numbers like this 30.2,00

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean to replace the trailing zeros in decimal numbers with commas like 1,50 and not numbers using commas to group digits into triplets, then search for `(\d*[.,](?:\d*[1-9]|))0*$` and replace it with `$1`

If the regex doesn't match your string, then there is no dot or comma present, which means there's no fractional part of the number, so you don't want to remove the trailing zeros because they are significant.

Remember that with regex, you need to escape the dot because it's a special symbol (except when between brackets), but you shouldn't escape the comma

Comment: You're assuming right these are prices which im receiving them with both delimiters(. and ,) so i have to remove the trailing zeros.And your expression is also right!!!

Comment: You' re right Karoly. Your code works for both, delimiters and traling zeros, removing them at once.The